# Life like paper in three.js

Tags: three.js

I am building a game. In my game is a scene where the character is reading a book. I have created pages of that book which should flip around and stuff. Using Three.js It is simple to crate a cube geo with some specs. My problem is that the paper or page representation is like a board. The paper should be floppy and flexible like paper.

That is where I am stuck. I looked into Physi.js but seems to be an overkill. Collision may be something I need in the future so that the pages do not assume the same exact plane, but for now I will settle for life-like. I looked at morphing but am unsure if that is the way to go.

I Have built a fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/e4hqdjbz/ 
It is only a single page with orbit controls though.

```
//PAPER
frontside = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/2837975/pexels-photo-2837975.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260' );
frontside.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

backside = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1001780/pexels-photo-1001780.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260' );
backside.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

edge = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( );
edge.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

materialArray1= [
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } ), //Right side
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } ), // Left Side
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } ), // Top
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } ), // Bottom
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: frontside } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: backside } ),
];

var geometry1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 23.3, 50, 0.005 );
var paper = new THREE.Mesh( geometry1, materialArray1 );
paper.position.set(0,0,0)
scene.add( paper );
```

Any thoughts on a direction I should head and why?

When flipping a page or paper, the animation should be more life-like, kinda flexible but not resistant. Adding physics with gravity, density and airflow may be the answer, but not sure.

Comment: Your question, which is basically "how can I make a plane look and act like a piece of paper" is a bit too broard I think.

Comment: I have updated the Fiddle to show page turning. FIrst problme will be collision. You can see that the boxes assume the same plane upon closing. Next is more life like. The question is not too broad. I asked which direction someone with experience would go in. Is it a morphing thing or something else?

Comment: As far as collision goes, it may not even be a collision thing. I know that the pages do or should not share the same z axis as in real life they also do not. I can tween them to their correct Z axis which would create the page order, but that seems like a poor hack and not a real three js thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a skinned mesh animation of the exact textured page animation, in Blender, either by you, or a 3d artist... export that animation as (gltf) .glb and load that in your app, and after the load completes, swap out the material.map s to whatever texture you want.

Comment: That does not stop collision or make the paper flexible as far as I know. That only creates the exact same thing I already have.

Comment: actually ok, I do see how that is a nicer end product. Thank you for the recommendation